# How to update NancyFX from version 1.2 to 1.4.4

Tags: c#, nancy

I am trying to update a web-application's NancyFX DLLs from version 1.2 to 1.4.*, and specifically the Nancy DLL to 1.4.4. While the update is successful, I get run-time errors that I'm unsure how to resolve.

## NancyFX DLL Versions

- Nancy

  - Current: 1.2.0
  - New: 1.4.4
- Nancy.Authentication.Forms

  - Current: 1.2.0
  - New: 1.4.1
- Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet

  - Current: 1.2.0
  - New: 1.4.1
- Nancy.Viewengines.Razor

  - Current: 1.2.0
  - New: 1.4.3

## Problem

Updating these DLLs to the newer version has the following issue:

[image: 500 Error]

I have read through this GitHub thread ( https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2093 ) which seems to have the exact same issue I am having - oddly, this is marked as closed, but I still have this issue. Supposedly, this pull request ( https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/2094 ) fixed the issue.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and resolved it? What steps did you take?

Alternatively, what are some things I can do to further diagnose what my particular problem might be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread explains the issue and the fix.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2093